# jquery: trouble identifying text area values from multiple identical forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms, textarea

I've got a form with id "#modelform". When #modelform is submitted, a second form appears with class identifier of ".waldform".  #modelform can be submitted several times, so this means that there will be a few .waldforms on my site. Each .waldform is pre populated with a default value that comes from the $counter variable. So the text area of the first .waldform  is populated with "1", the second with "2" and so on. This text area is a class called ".waldnum". When a .waldform is submitted, it calls the python function "wald", and sends the function its .waldnum.

However, this doesn't seem to be happening. Each .waldform is indeed population with the $counter variable but the .waldnum is not being updated. The .waldnum appears to keep its first value of "1".

Any thoughts?

```
var $counter = 0

$("#modelform").submit(function() {

    $counter++;

    $('body').append($counter) ;

    // post the form values via AJAX...
    $.post('/estimate', {name: $("#mymodel").val()}, function(data) {

        var $a_var = data['title']
        var $element = $('<div class="item">' + $a_var + '</div><br>');

        $('body').append($element) ;




        //create a waldform and set default value to $counter
        $('body').append('<form class="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" class="waldnum" value="' + $counter + '"/><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form>');

        $(".waldform").submit(function() {

        //post the form values via AJAX...
        $.post('/wald', {name: $(".waldnum").val()}, function(data) {

            $('body').append($(".waldnum").val());

            var $a_var = data['title']
            var $element = $('<div class="item">' + $a_var + '</div><br>');

            $('body').append($element);



            });

            return false ;
        });



    });

    return false ;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `$(".waldnum").val()` is getting the *first* `.waldnum` on the page, not the one inside the form being submitted.

Inside your submit function, go with something like:

`$(this).find('.waldnum').val()`

Which should give you the value for the form.